# Where is the global configuration for my $PATH variable set?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, path

I wanted to upgrade my Java version and ran into the problem, that my path contained a directory, that didn't exist anymore. I checked my .bashrc file, but it didn't modify anything path related. The /etc/environment file also just contained the default path. Does anybody know where the file for the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle/db/bin` section of the following path is stored?

```sh
user@server:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle/db/bin
```

Thanks

Edit: I forgot to mention, that I already checked the /etc/environment file. I fixed it by just reinstalling my server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the global bash configuration in

> /etc

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, that I had already checked that file. Well, I just reinstalled my server and fixed the problem in that way.